# Flip view like UIView.transition with Core Animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I want to create a transition between two views like `UIView.transition` with `.transitionFlipFromLeft`. For example:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    static let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200)
    
    let viewContainer = UIView(frame: frame)
    let view1 = UIView(frame: frame)
    let view2 = UIView(frame: frame)
    var currentView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view1.backgroundColor = .blue
        self.view2.backgroundColor = .red
        self.currentView = self.view1
        
        self.view.addSubview(self.viewContainer)
        self.viewContainer.addSubview(self.currentView)
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if currentView == view1 {
            flip(to: view2)
        } else {
            flip(to: view1)
        }
    }
    
    func flip(to toView: UIView) {
        UIView.transition(from: currentView,
                          to: toView,
                          duration: 1,
                          options: .transitionFlipFromLeft,
                          completion: { _ in self.currentView = toView })
    }

}
```

It should be possible to reach a similar effect by using Core Animation. I replaced `UIView.transition` in `func flip(to toView: UIView)`:

```swift
func flip(to toView: UIView) {
    var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    transform.m34 = -1 / 400
    toView.layer.transform = transform
    self.currentView.layer.transform = transform
    
    let disappearByRotating = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.y")
    disappearByRotating.duration = 0.5
    disappearByRotating.fromValue = 0
    disappearByRotating.toValue = CGFloat.pi / 2
    
    let appearByRotating = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.y")
    appearByRotating.duration = 0.5
    appearByRotating.fromValue = CGFloat.pi /  2
    appearByRotating.toValue = CGFloat.pi
    
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        self.currentView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.viewContainer.addSubview(toView) // <= Problem!
        toView.layer.add(appearByRotating, forKey: "appear")
        self.currentView = toView
    }
    self.currentView.layer.add(disappearByRotating, forKey: "disappear")
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

- I used two animations: In the first animation, the first view rotates from the left to the middle, in the second animation, the second view rotates from the middle to the right.

When I add the second view to my `viewContainer`, it is displayed untransformed before the second animation starts. This causes flickering:

[image]

How can I prevent the flickering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

- apply a 90-degree rotation to `toView.layer` before anything else
- `toView` will now be "invisible" so add it as a subview
- embed a new `CATransaction` with new `Completion Block` in the original Completion Block to "remove" the transform from `toView.layer`

Try this:

```
func flip(to toView: UIView) {
    var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    transform.m34 = -1 / 400
    // start toView rotated 90 degrees
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat.pi / 2, 0, 1, 0)
    toView.layer.transform = transform

    // because toView's layer is rotated 90 degrees, we can
    //  add the subview here and it won't be visible
    //  really no difference between .addSubview and .insertSubview for our purposes
    //  but we'll insert it under the current view anyway
    self.viewContainer.insertSubview(toView, belowSubview: self.currentView)

    transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    transform.m34 = -1 / 400
    self.currentView.layer.transform = transform
    
    let disappearByRotating = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.y")
    disappearByRotating.duration = 0.5
    disappearByRotating.fromValue = 0
    disappearByRotating.toValue = CGFloat.pi / 2
    disappearByRotating.fillMode = .forwards
    disappearByRotating.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    
    let appearByRotating = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.y")
    appearByRotating.duration = 0.5
    appearByRotating.fromValue = -CGFloat.pi /  2
    appearByRotating.toValue = 0
    appearByRotating.fillMode = .forwards
    appearByRotating.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        self.currentView.removeFromSuperview()
        // start a new CATransaction with new Completion Block
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            self.currentView.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "disappear")
            toView.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "appear")
            // remove 90-degree-rotation starting point from toView
            toView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
            self.currentView = toView
        }
        toView.layer.add(appearByRotating, forKey: "appear")
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
    self.currentView.layer.add(disappearByRotating, forKey: "disappear")
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Comment: On the simulator it looks perfect. Unfortunately on the device, it is still flickering. At the end of the first animation, its view returns to its initial size before the second animation starts. The second animation starts good, but the last frame is dropped. 

Comment: Whoops... hadn't checked it on a device.

Comment: Added a few lines to fix the remaining problems.

Comment: @andreas1724 - I had looked at `.isRemovedOnCompletion` but wasn't getting much... probably should have stuck with it... Looks like `.removeAnimation()` was also needed. Glad you've got it working.